# При вызове функции возникает ошибка "name is not defined" подскажите в чем причина, вот код

Tags: python

```
class Koesuoritus:
    def __init__(self, nimi: str, arvosana1: int, arvosana2: int, arvosana3: int):
        self.nimi = nimi
        self.arvosana1 = arvosana1
        self.arvosana2 = arvosana2
        self.arvosana3 = arvosana3

    def tulokset (suoritukset: list):
        return [max(suoritus) for suoritus in suoritukset] 
           

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'Nimi:{self.nimi}, arvosana1: {self.arvosana1}' +
            f', arvosana2: {self.arvosana2}, arvosana3: {self.arvosana3}')
           

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    suoritus1 = Koesuoritus("Pekka",5,3,4)
    suoritus2 = Koesuoritus("Pirjo",3,4,1)
    suoritus3 = Koesuoritus("Paavo",2,1,3)
    suoritukset = [suoritus1, suoritus2, suoritus3]
    print(tulokset(suoritukset))
```

Comment: Переводя с английского - переменная не определена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `tulokset` находится в классе `Koesuoritus`, поэтому мы должны вызывает метод класса `Koesuoritus.tulokset`, а не просто функцию. Питон не знает функцию с таким именем (вне класса), о чём и сообщает в ошибке:

```
print(Koesuoritus.tulokset(suoritukset))
```

---

Вижу, вы недавно начали изучать программирование. Думаю этот [самоучитель](https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python) вам поможет, особенно c [ООП](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/obektno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie-obshhee-predstavlenie.html).

Comment: Код всё равно не работает, так как функция `tulokset` реализована не правильно и я не до конца понимаю, что именно вы хотите сделать. Вы можете задать другой вопрос или получше изучить язык.

Comment: Здравствуйре! Спасибо за ответ.
Это учебное задание и его условие звучит так :  Надо написать функцию tulokset , которая должна возвращать  список только лучших результатов  из каждого Koesuoritus обьекта, результат должен быть таким : [5, 4, 3] 
Название функции и класса выглядит не обычно, просто они написаны на финском языке. Еще не догадался, как правильно написать функцию, не мог справиться с ошибкой ”name is not defined ”. 
А как бы Вы написали эту функцию чтобы получить требуемый результат?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Как понимаю, он должен возвращать максимальное значение из arvosana1, 2 и 3, верно? Я бы делал не `max(suoritus)` (он принимает итерируемый объект), а отдельный метод класса, который возвращает `max(self.arvosana1, ...)`. [Подучите язык](https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python), что бы лучше разбираться, что у вас происходит и что нужно делать. Удачи вам с изучением языка.

Comment: Да,все правильно. Спасибо за подсказку!